# Best way to store chat messages and files

Tags: php, doctrine, chat, storage, message

I would like to know what do you think about storing chat messages in a database?

I need to be able to bind other stuff to them (like files, or contacts) and using a database is the best way I see for now.

The same question comes for files, because they can be bound to chat messages, I have to store them in the database too..

With thousands of messages and files I wonder about performance drops and database size.

What do you think considering I'm using PHP with MySQL/Doctrine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it would be OK to store any textual information on the database (names, messages history, etc) provided that you structure your database properly. I have worked for big Web-sites (multi-kilo visits a day) and telecom companies that store information about their users (including their traffic statistics) on the databases that have grown up to hundreds of gigabytes and the applications were working fine.

But regarding binary information like images and files it would be better to store them on the file systems and store only their paths on the database, because it will be cheaper to read them off the disks that to tie a database process to reading a multi-megabyte file.

As I said, it is important that you do several things:

1. Structure you information properly - it is very important to properly design your database, properly divide it into tables and tables into fields with your performance goals in mind because this will form the basis for your application and queries. Get that wrong and your queries will be slow.
2. Make proper decisions on table engines pertinent to every table. This is an important step because it will greatly affect the performance of your queries. For example, MyISAM blocks reading access to the table while it is being updated. That will be a problem for a web application like a social networking or a news site because im many situations your users will basically have to wait for a information update to be completed before the will see a generated page.
3. Create proper indexes - very important for performance, especially for applications with rapidly growing big databases.
4. Measure performance of your queries as data grows and look for the ways to improve it - you will always find bottlenecks that have to be removed, this is an ongoing non-stop process. Every popular web application has to do it.

Comment: Yes, of course files will not be stored on the database, but having an entry storing their paths would be really useful to store additional data and link them to other entities.
Also, not all messages require a specific entry, so it may be a good idea to regroup "simple messages" into a same database entry.

I'm not particularly aware of database design optimization, do you have some related link?

Comment: There are some tips here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27281
and in this presentation:
http://www.slideshare.net/ronaldbradford/top-20-design-tips-for-mysql-data-architects-presentation
You can also read selected chapters on storage engines, table types, application design, query optimization in the books Beginning MySQL Database Design and Optimization: From Novice to Professional (http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-MySQL-Database-Design-Optimization/dp/1590593324) and High Performance MySQL (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003067.do)

Comment: Ok thanks for the links, but what do think about Doctrine in terms of optimization? Is it a good idea to do high frequency requests using an ORM? I also think many requests optimizations discussed in the documents you linked are handled by Doctrine.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to squeeze every bit of performance out of the system, it is better to stick to PDO and write your own custom database handling library specifically for your case on top of it. It is only a bit slower than raw mysql_* requests, while Doctrine and other ORMs add a lot of overhead and will be the bottleneck when you need to scale. PDO has everything you need including prepared statements that mysql_* functions don't have. It also supports object-oriented interface. On the other hand, using PDO you can then easily switch say from MySQL to Oracle should you need to.

Comment: Regarding optimization, it is always better to do it yourself in a "monitor" - "find a bottleneck" - "optimize" non-stop cycle rather than rely on some third-party solution because you should implement only those optimizations that are needed by your system and  when they are needed and nothing else.

Comment: Sorry for the response time. So the best way to go should be to have a light custom library on top of PDO to handle high frequency requests like chat messages records and use Doctrine for the rest.

My main worry was on the number of records (thousands of entries), and I'm happy to see the idea to store high number of entries like chat messages in a database is conceivable.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a NoSQL database like CouchDB or MongtoDB is an option. You can also store the files separate and link them via a known filename but it depends on your system architecture.

Comment: any particular reason?